# How to grep for line numbers in a binary file?

Tags: centos, grep, tail, binary-files, head

I'm on Centos 5 Linux and using GNU grep v2.5.1 and looking at a 36GB log file.  It is huge and I need to find around a million lines starting from the occurrence of a string `6307459` in the log file and view it in emacs.  I'm using `grep` to find the line number of the occurrence and then using `head` and `tail` to get the section I'm interested in reviewing.  The issue I'm facing is that `grep` finds the line but does not give it to me, instead printing message about it being a binary file:

```
> grep -n 6307459 /disk2/user/test/logs/2015-03-31-23-42-52-7224.log 
Binary file /disk2/user/test/logs/2015-03-31-23-42-52-7224.log matches
```

I imagine somewhere in the log file are some control characters that are tricking grep, but the beginning and end of the file looks like normal text.

I tried renaming it to /disk2/user/test/logs/2015-03-31-23-42-52-7224.log.txt, but it still says it is a binary file.

How can I get the line number of the occurrence of the pattern 6307459 in the file so that I can use `head` and `tail` to see 20 lines before the pattern and 1,000,000 after the pattern?

Comment: See: [How do I grep through binary files that look like text?](http://serverfault.com/questions/328101/how-do-i-grep-through-binary-files-that-look-like-text) at serverfault SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per s g's [linked answer from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/328101/how-do-i-grep-through-binary-files-that-look-like-text), passing `-a` to `grep` forces binary files to be treated as text files.  Here is the detailed solution:

```
> grep -a -n 6307459 /disk2/user/test/logs/2015-03-31-23-42-52-7224.log
171560394:Rcvd client's reconnect count 6307459.
```

Using the found line number of `171560394`, I then created the following command to get a million lines starting at 100 lines before the found pattern so that I can view it in emacs:

```
> head -n 172560294 /disk2/user/test/logs/2015-03-31-23-42-52-7224.log  \
  | tail -n 1000000 > /disk2/user/test/logs/2015-03-31-23-42-52-7224.log_mid
```